# How can I access attribute from service method in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to pass a token from Spotify API to a service method in Angular so I have an endpoint that gets the token and works, but when I call the getQuery() method The output object of 'headers' is something like:

```js
{
    Authorization: Bearer undefined
}
```

So because of this, when I want to make a request, it throws a 401 status because my access token is not correct.

This is what my service and constructor method looks like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpotifyService {


  private token:string

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient,

  ) {
    const clientId = 'my client id';
    const clientSecret = 'my client secret';
    this.getToken(clientId, clientSecret);

  }
```

and this is what my getToken() method looks like:

```js
getToken(clientId:string, clientSecret:string){
    const urlRequest = `https://myendpoint/${clientId}/${clientSecret}`;
    this.http.get(urlRequest)
              .subscribe( (data:any) =>{
                this.token = data.access_token;
              });
  }
```

At this point everything is ok, but when I call this service from a component and I call another service method, looks like the constructor does not execute because I get the undefined issue on this service method:

```js
getQuery( query:string ){

    const url = `https://spotifyapi/${query}`;

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
    });
    console.log(headers);
    return this.http.get(url,{headers});
  }
```

I used `console.log()` to check if I'm getting the token in getToken() and it works but it seems that I can't access to it from `getQuery()` method.

I just want to make accessible the token in that method so I can make requests.

Comment: Guess when you send your query, `getToken` hasn't done yet at this time token is undefined

Comment: You should consider looking at operators such as switchMap to “chain” these calls together in the desired order as well as moving logic out of the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since `this.http.get` is an asyncronous call, you should wait till the call is finished. You can have it this way base on how you implement it:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SpotifyService {

   // Changing its type from a simple string to an Observable<string>
   private token$: Observable<string>;

   constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
     const clientId     = 'my client id';
     const clientSecret = 'my client secret';

     // Initialize the token
     this.token = this.getToken(clientId, clientSecret);
   }

   getToken(clientId:string, clientSecret:string): Observable<any> {
      const urlRequest = `https://myendpoint/${clientId}/${clientSecret}`;

      // Call the token api and get only its "access_token"
      return this.http.get(urlRequest).pipe(map(data => data.access_token));
   }

   getQuery( query:string ){

     const url = `https://spotifyapi/${query}`;

     // Subscribe to the token$ observable and assign the token on your headers
     this.token$.subscribe(token => {

       const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}` });

       console.log(headers);

       return this.http.get(url, {headers});
     });

   }


}
```

---

> Another way is to use **HTTP Interceptor**

1.) After you login, usually it will then give you the token. Store that token on your localStorage

`localStorage.setItem('token:id', token);`

2.) Create `auth.interceptor.ts`

> With this, everytime you call your API, it will automatically insert your headers

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      const token = localStorage.getItem('token:id');

      if (token) {
         const cloned = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`) });
         return next.handle(cloned);
      }
      else return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

3.) Import it on your `AppModule` or `CoreModule` (if you have)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
       provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
       useClass: AuthInterceptor,
       multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i see couple of problems with the way you are trying to solve the problem. As pointed out in the comments, the token might not have fetched before the call was made.
Consider making following changes

1. use APP_INITIALIZER to preload the token, that way its guaranteed
   that you will have the token before your app starts loading - have a
   look at -
   https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-how-to-use-app-initializer/
2. If the auth token is required in each call, you shouldn't be adding
   the header in every service, consider adding a http interceptor to add the auth header before each service - https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8